# Regex for "wp-admin" "wp-login" entries in syslog trying on drupal sites

Tags: regex, drupal, fail2ban

I am looking for a fail2ban regex (or two) to find the wp-admin and wp-login attemps on drupal sites.
The regex should find "drupal:" and  "page not found" and ("wp-admin" or "wp-login")
the problem for me are the "and" conditions
The logfile entries:

```
Apr  7 10:59:23 webserver drupal: https://www.anywebsite.com|1617785962|page not found|123.456.789.112|https://www.anywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=revslider_show_image&img=../wp-config.php|https://anywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=revslider_show_image&img=../wp-config.php|0||wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Apr  7 06:53:47 webserver drupal: https://www.anywebsite.com|1617771227|page not found|123.456.789.112|https://www.anywebsite.com/wp/wp-login.php||0||wp/wp-login.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
failregex = ^\s*\S+ drupal: [^|]*\|\d+\|(?:page not found)\|<ADDR>
```

- replace `<ADDR>` with `<HOST>` for fail2ban versions before v.0.10

**WARNING** Note that this assumes that first URI in your log-line (site? referrer?) after `drupal:`  never contains a pipe-character (so an intruder is unable to add it to URI somehow to avoid ban). Otherwise it becomes complex (you must anchor it from both sides or write some conditional REs with lookaheads or lookbehinds).
Also note that if your side can make some 404 for legitimate users (because missing some references etc), you have to add to the RE some precise pattern excluding your missing pages to avoid false positives, e. g. something like this (with blacklisting expressions):

```
_block_uris = wp-admin|(?:wp/)wp-login
failregex = ^\s*\S+ drupal: [^|]*\|\d+\|(?:page not found)\|<ADDR>\|\w+://[^/]+/(?:%(_block_uris)s)
```

or (with white-listing expressions, here ignoring `/my-page/` and `my-site/` URIs):

```
_ignore_uris = my-page/|my-side/
failregex = ^\s*\S+ drupal: [^|]*\|\d+\|(?:page not found)\|<ADDR>\|\w+://[^/]+/(?!%(_ignore_uris)s)
```